# Update SQL Table based on column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large set of data that needs to be updated based on price.  Very simply, the price of an item in Code/Size 1 must be equal to or less than the Code/Size 2.  Code/Size 2 must be equal to or less than Code/Size 3, and so on:

```
Item       Code   Size  Price   
-------------------------------
66227019    OTH     1   $466
66227019    OTH     2   $486
66227019    OTH     3   $476
66227019    OTH     4   $537

66227019    IVC     1   $458
66227019    IVC     2   $428
66227019    IVC     3   $458
66227019    IVC     4   $458
```

Must look like:

```
Item       Code   Size  Price   
-------------------------------
66227019    OTH     1   $466
66227019    OTH     2   $486
66227019    OTH     3   $486
66227019    OTH     4   $537

66227019    IVC     1   $458
66227019    IVC     2   $458
66227019    IVC     3   $458
66227019    IVC     4   $458
```

I've tried some self-joins and I'm basically losing my mind.  Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL-Server or other DBMS? Version?

Comment: Maybe I'm going blind, but what is different in your desired result?

Comment: You'd like to increase the price for an { Item, Code, Size } entry, if there's another record with the same Item and Code and lower Size with a greater Price?

Comment: @Andrew some of the prices have been raised - according to the requirements.

Comment: @ypercube I am working with SQL Server 2012

Comment: So oth/2 must be >= oth/1, etc?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades precisely

Comment: Check out the lag function, maybe?  It's new to 2012, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL-Server 2012, you can use this:

```
; WITH cte AS
( SELECT *,
         MaxPrice = MAX(Price) 
                    OVER (PARTITION BY Item, Code
                          ORDER BY Size
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                   AND 1 PRECEDING
                         ) 
  FROM Products
) 
UPDATE cte
SET Price = MaxPrice
WHERE Price < MaxPrice ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63b44/1)**

Comment: this did the trick!  thanks again and i'll have to look up the ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING.  Never seen that one before.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you what you need?

```
UPDATE LaterRec
SET Price = PrevRec.Price
FROM Data AS LaterRec
    INNER JOIN Data AS PrevRec ON LaterRec.Item = PrevRec.Item AND LaterRec.Code = PrevRec.Code AND PrevRec.Size < LaterRec.Size
WHERE
        PrevRec.Price > LaterRec.Price
    -- Disregard this entry if there's a record *between* PrevRec and LaterRec
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Data AS Intrmdt WHERE LaterRec.Item = Intrmdt.Item AND LaterRec.Code = Intrmdt.Code AND Intrmdt.Size > PrevRec.Size AND Intrmdt.Size < LaterRec.Size)
```

Answer (score 1):

answer is Recursive CTE. not depends on the SQL SERVER version.

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
        item        INT
        ,code       sysname
        ,SIZE       INT
        ,price      INT
    )
    INSERT INTO @t( item, code, SIZE, price )
                SELECT 1,'oth',1,466
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'oth',2,486
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'oth',3,476
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'oth',4,537

    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'ivc',1,458
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'ivc',2,428
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'ivc',3,458
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'ivc',4,458

    SELECT * FROM @t

    ;WITH cte1 (item,code,size,price,rownum1,rownum2)
    AS
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item,code ORDER BY item,code,SIZE) AS rownum1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item,code,SIZE) AS rownum2
        FROM @t
    ),  
    cte2 (item,code,size,price,rownum1,rownum2)
    AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM cte1 t1
        WHERE rownum2=1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t1.item,t1.code,t1.size
                ,CASE   WHEN t1.price>=t2.price THEN t1.price 
                        WHEN t1.price<t2.price THEN t2.price
                END AS proce
                ,t1.rownum1,t1.rownum2
        FROM cte2 t2
        JOIN cte1 t1
            ON t2.rownum2+1=t1.rownum2
    )
    SELECT item,code,size,price FROM cte2
```

[image]

Comment: Recursive CTEs can be quite expensive - since the OP is on SQL Server 2012 I'd favor the more efficient solution available to them.

Comment: Well it is expensive if not implemented correctly and fetches unnecessary data. But yes OP is for SQL 2012 so new feature can be used depending on its performance. I haven't compare the performance though.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `t` is your table's name:

```
update t set price=p
from (
  select nxt.item i,nxt.code c,nxt.size s,max(cur.price) p
  from t cur join t nxt 
  on (cur.item=nxt.item and cur.code=nxt.code 
   and cur.size<nxt.size and cur.price>nxt.price)
  group by nxt.item,nxt.code,nxt.size      
  ) a
where item=i and code=c and size=s
```

Comment: If there are multiple records for the same Item and Code with a lower Size, won't this query return multiple records, and therefore not be able to update?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: Do you mean, for example, if the 4th price was changed to, say, 477?

Comment: But `cur` joins to each record with a lower Size, each time as `nxt`.  I don't see where you're removing duplicates.  For example, if { OTH, 4 } was $0, the table would self join 4 to 3, and also 4 to 2, and 4 to 1.

Comment: You may have a point, but I'm too tired right now... I'll look into it some other time.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: After a (semi-)good night's sleep I managed to get my braincells in some order and set this straight. Thanks for the _brain fuse_ :)